# (Angular) Should Entry Components count as Dumb Components?

Tags: angular, architecture, reactive-programming

I'm refactoring my code into Smart and Dumb Components.
However, I don't know whether an entry component is a Dumb Component or not?

Should I put it to another module (Dumb Component Module) or put it inside Smart Component Module and just declare it inside `entryComponents` property or not?

**This is my entry component**

```
export class ComfirmBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ConfirmBoxModel
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  confirm() {
    ...
  }

  cancel() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

**This is how I call it**

```
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmBoxComponent, configData);
```

Comment: Why would you have separate modules for dumb and smart components? Have a look at [the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), maybe you get some inspiration from there.

Comment: btw, entryComponents are [depreciated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required) and not needed since v9.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis Current I am using Angular version 7 since it is the company requirement